# Audit trail as XML on physical file system in Windows

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, audit

**OS:**
Windows 2008 (x64) Enterprise Edition

**Database :**
Oracle 11g R2 Enterprise Edition

Audit Parameters are :
[image]

**Requirement :**
We need to be get Audit file on the mentioned path as shown in "audit_file_dest",

I searched [and found that](http://www.dba-oracle.com/security/detection.htm):

> There is no equivalent system for writing audit records to a file
>   system in Windows. The parameter audit_file_dest does not exist on the
>   Windows platform. All the audit records go to the Event Log.
>
> In the Windows environment, you would want to check the Event Log.
>   These OS trails are recorded under Application Event Logs.

We are getting audit information in Event Viewer, but is there any way to get it on the file system? The above link is talking about Oracle 9i; can any one confirm that all audit logs still being written to the Event Log in Windows in Oracle 11gR2?

Comment: Have you tried it, or looked [at the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e36292/auditing.htm#CEGHHFBF) rather than third-party info? "If you set the XML value, then also set the AUDIT_FILE_DEST parameter. For all platforms, including Windows, the default location for XML audit trail records is...". And [this too](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e36292/auditing.htm#BCGJHGGC). The Event Log applies to OS, but you're specifically asking about XML.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I will check the documentation you mentioned